# Ionic on platform size change

Tags: html, ionic-framework

I have a function that I want to call whenever the user's platform size changes, to preserve formatting. This could occur because of a rotation, or resizing a browser window on the web app, etc. I am currently using Ionic 3 and Angular 4.

I have contemplated storing `platform.width()` and `platform.height()` as local variables, and then basically have a function with a set interval like

```
myFunction() {
    if(this.storedWidth != this.platform.width() 
        || this.storedHeight != this.platform.height() {

      // do stuff
      this.storedWidth = this.platform.width();
      this.storedHeight = this.platform.height();
    }
}

...

setInterval(myFunction, 100);
```

But this solution seems inefficient and frankly a little bashy. But if this "listener" is the only way to do it, I will settle with that.

Thoughts?

Comment: there is a platform.resize event emitter. Maybe subscribe to it and listen for changes?

Comment: @AnjilDhamala i'll look into that. But it says it only works with Cordova, so it might not answer my question fully. https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform/#resize

Comment: I see. Are you doing like a progressive web app thing with Ionic?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if this would work but you could fool angular into tracking a platform's size by setting an input() field to the platform.width() and implement OnChanges() and track changes in ngOnChanges() function.